# how to split name and email address in php or using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have following string:

```
"Test, User" < test@test.com >, "Another, Test" < another@test.com >, .........
```

I want following result:

```
array(
  array('name' => 'Test, User', 'email' => 'test@test.com'),
  array('name' => 'Another, Test', 'email' => 'another@test.com'),  
  ...........
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) seems appropriate:

```
$in = '"Test, User" < test@test.com >, "Another, Test" < another@test.com >, .........';
preg_match_all('!"(.*?)"\s+<\s*(.*?)\s*>!', $in, $matches);
$out = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($matches[0]); $i++) {
  $out[] = array(
    'name' => $matches[1][$i],
    'email' => $matches[2][$i],
  );
}
print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test, User
            [email] => test@test.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Another, Test
            [email] => another@test.com
        )

)
```

Comment: Would it be better if you use [^<>] instead of the . in the name. Then you can let the dot(.) be greedy? You could do for both the dots too.

Comment: @Jass: Are there any advantages of dot being greedy?

Comment: @serg555 ! is not used as a part of the regex here. Its a tokenizer in php for the regex !...! defines start and end of the regex

Comment: serg555: "!" has no special meaning in regex. In this example it's used as a token character in place of the more common "/" as allowed by Perl compatible regular expressions.

Comment: Often non-greedy wildcards provide a cleaner solution than, say, [^"] but usually those can work too.

Comment: @serg555 i meant token not tokenizer.. And about the dot being greedy. I just think it would be slightly faster than a lazy one. but  in case of failure it would backtrack and slow down in case of no match. [you could make it an atomic regex to fail fast and avoid useless backtracking]

Comment: @cletus ah yeah i agree about the cleaner solution. ? is easier to read as compared to a negated character class for a beginner atleast.

Answer (score 2):

I combined this answer with another here to create a rather complete parser:

```
function parseEmailListToArray($list) {
    $t = str_getcsv($list);

    foreach($t as $k => $v) {
        if (strpos($v,',') !== false) {
            $t[$k] = '"'.str_replace(' <','" <',$v);
        }
    }

    foreach ($t as $addr) {
        if (strpos($addr, '<')) {
            preg_match('!(.*?)\s?<\s*(.*?)\s*>!', $addr, $matches);
            $emails[] = array(
                'email' => $matches[2],
                'name' => $matches[1]
            );
        } else {
            $emails[] = array(
                'email' => $addr,
                'name' => ''
            );
        }
    }

    return $emails;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) by pattern matching the:

```
"Test, User" < test[at]test.com >,
```

Then [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to find the name and email components, then put them in an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$strs = preg_split($in,'".*" < .* >,');
foreach ($strs as $str){
$in1 = preg_match('/".+"/', $str);
$in2 = preg_match('/< .+ >/', $str);
push($out,array('name'=>$in1,'email'=>$in2);
}
echo $out;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, but working from the answer by cletus I expanded the regex to:

```
$regex = '/(("([^"]*)"|[^",]*)\\s*<(.*?)>|[^",\\s]+)(?=(,|$))/';
preg_match_all($regex,$in,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
$out = [];
foreach($matches as $match) $out[] = [
  'name' => $match[3] ?: trim($match[2]),
  'email' => trim($match[4]) ?: $match[1]
];
```

This will also match a simple `foo@acme.com` or `<bar@acme.com>` (`name` will be empty then), and a name without surrounding quotes.